# Deploy online web builder

Tags: web-apps, web-development

we are looking for an off the shelf web builder that we can expose to users on our site that they can use to create a basic website for themselves.  The tools should be an easy drag and drop type tool.

Does anyone have any ideas on which tools exist that we can use for that without having to develop it from scratch ? We are aware of CMS tools like Joomla and Wordpress but we need tools that are more basic and more "webbuilder" flavored.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Searching the web for white label and self hosted web builders yields a few possibilities. The most popular / likely solutions seem to be:

- https://bloxby.com
- http://builderengine.org (Community Edition Available)
- https://www.devhub.com/small-business-website-builder
- https://www.duda.co/website-builder
- https://www.imcreator.com/whitelabel
- https://www.iscripts.com/easycreate
- https://microweber.com/pricing#white-label
- https://pagestead.com
- https://welcome.setseed.com
- https://www.silex.me (Free)
- https://simvoly.com/whitelabel-website-builder
- http://www.sitebuilderbuilder.com/whitelabel-sitebuilder-features
- https://sitegalore.com
- https://site.pro
- https://www.ucraft.com/whitelabel
- https://ukit.com
- https://www.vendasta.com/marketplace/website-builder